# Slicing an image in iOS

Tags: ios, image

I'm currently looking for a method to slice an image (one grabbed from the photo library, for instance) into a number of different rectangular pieces. Can anybody perhaps point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
CGImageRef topLeftImageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect(originalImage.CGImage, CGRectMake(0,0,originalImage.size.width/2,originalImage.size.height/2));

UIImage *topLeftImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:topLeftImageRef];
```

Comment: @James Glad I could help!  Would you mind accepting my answer?